# NodeJS: Request ISO-8859-1 encoded content

Tags: node.js, encoding

I just want store in Mongo (so in UTF8) the content of a RSS feed. But I cannot even download content properly encoded :

```
var request = require('request');
var iconv = require('iconv');

var feedTest = function(url) {

request(url, {timeout: 20000}, function(error, resp, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(url + " : " + error);
    }
    else
    {
        var ic = new iconv.Iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8');
        var buf = ic.convert(body);
        var buffer = buf.toString('utf-8');
        console.log(resp.statusCode);
        console.log(buffer);
    }
});
};

feedTest("http://feeds.feedburner.com/spin-off-actu");
```

The accent are not in clear. No problem in PHP with iconv, but with this NodeJS code what is wrong?

Comment: Is the problem the same if you save to a file and open it in an editor? I'm unsure of the character set of `console.log` to a terminal.

Comment: Yes same issue, actually set the encoding to null in request options does the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The request module is already decoding `body` into a `utf8` string. If you tell it not to decode the response first, your code works great.

```
{timeout: 20000, encoding: null}
```

Comment: Ha it's a default value? Thats why this code works: https://gist.github.com/ebuildy/f374ed0cff4f98e85c67 (I force the encoding to binary).

Comment: Yup! Passing `null` just keeps it as a Buffer, so you don't needlessly convert it to a binary string and back to a Buffer before decoding.